# Trying to cout stars based on numbers

Tags: c++

I am trying a simple program that prints out stars according to number that has been entered, if the number is negative then program prints "Try Again!" and you need to enter numbers while you finish with 5 different positive numbers. Also the range should be from 1 to 30. I see that I am going deeper underground, feels like I am stuck here. Else after while is failing of course. Any tips? :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int myNumber = 0; 
    char star='*';
    bool flag = false;

    int counter = 0;

    while(!flag && counter <= 5){
        if(myNumber < 0  && myNumber > 30){
            cout << "Try Again!" << endl;
        }


        cout << "Enter 5 numbers: " << endl;
        cout << "-> ";
        cin >> myNumber;


        if(myNumber >0 && myNumber <= 30){
            flag = true;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < myNumber; i++){
            cout << star;
        }
        counter++;
    }


return 0;

}
```

Expected output is as follows:

```
Enter 5 numbers:
-> 4
* * * *
-> 10
* * * * * * * * * *
-> 7
* * * * * * *
-> -5
Try again!
-> 5
* * * * *
-> 12
* * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? One obvious thing: It can't print `Try Again` since you didn't put that anywhere in the code.

Comment: Also, there appears to be exactly one statement in the shown code that reads exactly one number. There is no looping of any kind. So, how exactly do you expect that to read five numbers?

Comment: I am trying to while lopp while the total number count is 5 and then program ends. Also the number range is 1 to 30. for loop with stars without while works as a charm, but only with one entered number. So while the totalNumbers have not reached number 5, user gets input and need to enter number from 1 to 30. With negative number he gets "Try Again!".

Comment: So after `cin >> myNumber;` you want to check `if` `myNumber` is `<` 0 or `>` 5` and `cout << "Try Again\n";` if that's the case?

Comment: So, after cin I want to have a function that reads 5 cin until the total number of cin is 5. Also the range for entered numbers is 1 to 30. Added break; after for loop, so I stopped endless loop.

Comment: Could you add some expected output, for some possible inputs? That would be more useful than a vague description of what should happen.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my post.

Comment: That edit makes it much easier to help you solve your problem. Definitely do the same on future "how do I do this" code questions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I learn fast so, no probs. :) Kinda new here, but see that this is a great way to learn programming.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this code:

- While loops do not need else blocks. The condition in the while () clause is supposed to be enough to get it to stop.
- break statements should be used inside of loops, not outside of loops.
- `totalNumbers` is never changed, so it will never be larger than 5, so the while loop will never be stopped. Remember that the check for totalNumbers will be evaluated after every run inside the loop, to determine if it should run again.
- You need a check after taking user input to ensure the input numbers are between 1 and 30
- and others.

Some changes to make:

- your `cin` command should be in the while loop
- you need to change totalNumbers after each correct `cin` and star output so that it eventually halts the while loop
- you need an if/else block inside the while loop, after `cin`, to verify the input is between 1 and 30.
- you need a way to print a string of stars with a variable length; you could use a for-loop for that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure what you mean by, "and you need to enter numbers while you finish with 5 different positive numbers."

If you wanted to prompt the user for input (of non-negative numbers) and then print out n-number of asterisks for the number the user has input I would:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int myNumber = 0;
    char star='*';
    bool flag = false;

    while(!flag){
        if(myNumber < 0){
             std::cout << "Try again!" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Enter number: ";
        std::cin >> myNumber;
        if(myNumber >0 && myNumber <= 30){
             flag = true;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < myNumber; i++){
         std::cout << star;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps in some way!

Comment: Hi Nilan. Yes, I just wanted to say that program asks user to enter number 5 times and then close the program. If during the loop user enters, for example, -6, program couts "Try Again" until user has been entered positive number 5 times. I am working on this, thank you for the advice.

Comment: So I have made some changes to the code, but seems that my idea with that counter does not work.